# PHP/MYSQL INSERT ON DUPLICATE KEY fail

Tags: php, mysql

I'm just tinkering with a simple timesheet script and if I do a simple insert into the db all is well. I can update the entry no problem either, my issue is that I want to update AND keep the information (which was working fine with the CONCAT I was using) but as soon as I use the ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE it breaks.

```
$sql="INSERT INTO sheet(employee, workdate, location, description, timein, timeout, timespent)
VALUES('$employee', CURDATE(), '$location', '$description', '$timein', '$timeout', '$timespent')";
//ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE
//location=VALUES(location),
//description=VALUES(description),
//timein=VALUES(timein),
//timeout=VALUES(timeout),
//timespent=VALUES(timespent)
//WHERE employee=$employee";
echo $sql;echo "<br>";
mysql_query($sql)or die(mysql_error());
```

If I uncomment the duplicate key I get a "You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near 'WHERE employee='Eric'' at line 9" error. Only thing I can think of is I'm doing this on a totally empty table but I figured the INSERT would have fixed that up. All my $variables are clean (no PDO, gotta learn that too) just real_escape_string

```
$sql="INSERT INTO sheet(employee, workdate, location, description, timein, timeout, timespent)
VALUES('$employee', CURDATE(), '$location', '$description', '$timein', '$timeout', '$timespent')
ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE
location=VALUES(location),
description=VALUES(description),
timein=VALUES(timein),
timeout=VALUES(timeout),
timespent=VALUES(timespent)
WHERE employee='$employee'";
echo $sql;echo "<br>";
mysql_query($sql)or die(mysql_error());
```

Comment: What version of MySQL server are you using?

Comment: I'm running this on 5.5 through Webmatrix for testing then I upload to my webhost when I'm happy.

Comment: Remove the `WHERE` condition, mySQL already knows.

Comment: The reason I have that is because for each employee on each day I want to be able to update all the information based on WHERE employee='$employee' AND workdate=CURDATE() as I just want on table entry per person per day.

Comment: `ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE` will only ever update the single record for which the keys conflict. You *cannot* have a `WHERE` condition in it, period.

Comment: well then, my bad. After all my searching it was such a simple answer. Thank you Sammitch.

Comment: Dude, you didn't read the docs

Answer (score 1):

According to the documentation for [INSERT ... ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/insert-on-duplicate.html), there should not be a WHERE statement at the end of your query:

```
$sql="INSERT INTO sheet(employee, workdate, location, description, timein, timeout, timespent)
VALUES('$employee', CURDATE(), '$location', '$description', '$timein', '$timeout', '$timespent')
ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE
location=VALUES(location),
description=VALUES(description),
timein=VALUES(timein),
timeout=VALUES(timeout),
timespent=VALUES(timespent)";
```

Notes:

- mysql_* functions are now deprecated. Read [http://fr.php.net/manual/en/mysqlinfo.api.choosing.php](http://php.net/manual/en/mysqlinfo.api.choosing.php) for more information.

> Recommended API It is recommended to use either the mysqli or
>   PDO_MySQL extensions. It is not recommended to use the old mysql
>   extension for new development, as it has been deprecated as of PHP
>   5.5.0 and will be removed in the future. A detailed feature comparison matrix is provided below. The overall performance of all three
>   extensions is considered to be about the same. Although the
>   performance of the extension contributes only a fraction of the total
>   run time of a PHP web request. Often, the impact is as low as 0.1%.

- if you have not already done so, you must properly escape the text variables before using them in your query:

  ```
  $employee = mysql_real_escape_string($employee);
  // and so on with the other variables
  ```

Read [How does this SQL injection work?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/332365/1409082) and [Why shouldn't I use mysql_* functions in PHP?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/12859942/1409082) to learn more on these topics.

Answer (score 0):

Don't use a `WHERE` clause with `ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE`. The `WHERE` is implied by the duplicate key.

Answer (score 0):

eg:

```
INSERT INTO table (a,b,c) VALUES (1,2,3)
  ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE c=c+1;

UPDATE table SET c=c+1 WHERE a=1;
```

if your first column i.e here employee is unique that would be considered for where clause internally

WHERE employee='$employee'

if it wasn't unique  it will look for workdate, ...

```
INSERT INTO sheet(employee, workdate, location, description, timein, timeout, timespent)
VALUES('$employee', CURDATE(), '$location', '$description', '$timein', '$timeout', '$timespent')
ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE
[
//columns to be update
location=VALUES(location),
description=VALUES(description),
timein=VALUES(timein),
timeout=VALUES(timeout),
timespent=VALUES(timespent)
]
```

Answer (score -1):

Put the employee in tics. If it is a string it has to have quotes around it. Also put curly braces around the variable.

Comment: sorry, it does have ticks '$employee' I just had them removed because I wanted to see if it made a difference. I've tried with `'" doesn't fix it :(